# What is the probability of observing two or fewer 6s when rolling a fair die ten times?

Tags: probability

What is the probability of observing two or fewer 6s when rolling a fair die ten times?

I'm thrown off by the "two or fewer" could use some help, thanks in advance!

Comment: Two or fewer means not three or greater.  It also means zero, one or two.  Each gives an approach to the problem.

Comment: So, do I calculate the probability of 0, 1, and 2 and add it together to get the answer?

Comment: Yes, that'll do it.  Just be careful that you are counting exactly one 6, and exactly two 6s.

Answer (score 1):

P(0): $(\frac 5 6) ^ {10}$ = 0.16151 
P(1): ${10}*(\frac 1 6 * (\frac 5 6)^9)$ = 0.32301 
P(2): $45 * ((\frac 1 6)^2 * (\frac 5 6)^8)$ = 0.29071

Total = P(0)+P(1)+P(2) = 0.16151 + 0.32301 + 0.29071 = 0.77523